# Identity in sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy

I want this to become this

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find it. Just tell me the name of the function. It's enough

1

> (5*y-3*x)**2

to:

> 25*y-30*x*y+9*x*2
> How?

please help me!

I tested with factor() and it didn't work !

Comment: To check equality, [you can't use `==`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs). Instead you could `simplify` one expression from the other and check whether the result is `0`. E.g. `print(simplify(A**2+1/A**2 - ((A+1/A)**2-2)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand()`

```
>>> expand((x + 1)**2)
 2
x  + 2⋅x + 1

>>> expand((x + 2)*(x - 3))
 2
x  - x - 6
```

from
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html#expand